# IPsec with various subnets on one side

Tags: vpn, routing, cisco-asa, ipsec, ios

I have the following situation:

```
Client subnet(192.168.0.0 /24) ----> Router ----> Internet ----> 
           ASA(172.17.0.2 /24) ----> 
       (172.17.0.1 /24)Gateway ----> (10.0.0.0 /8)Many subnets
```

I need to logically connect the client subnet to the "many subnets". On the left side I have a Cisco 2901 and on the other an ASA. I built an IPsec connection between the router and the ASA. The IPsec connection itself works but I cannot access any address behind the gateway. 
The local network of the IPsec connection is the `10.0.0.0/8` network.

The ASA doesn't get it that it has to route the traffic through the gateway `(172.17.0.1)`. I already set a default route on the inside interface to `10.0.0.0` `255.0.0.0.0` `172.17.0.1` but that doesn't work...

How can I tell the ASA that it has to route all traffic through the gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the "many subnets" to your protected network.

Router should have 192.168.0.0/24 as his protected network.
ASA should have the "*many subnets*" as his protected networks.

Also, unless you checked the "**Do not translate VPN traffic**", you will need to add a NAT rule in the ASA (172.17.0.2) in order to let the VPN traffic traverse the ASA.

Your NAT rule should be a static one if you need both sides to initiate a connection.

Comment: The problem is that the traffic don't get routed to the gateway. I see the incoming traffic in the logs on the ASA. The traffic just don't get routed to the gateway.

Comment: Does the ASA have an interface with an IP within the 172.17.0.1/24 subnet?